# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS boot problem

Tags: partitioning, grub2, uefi

Let me explain.
I bought new laptop. HP i5 10th generation with 8gb Ram and 256GB SSD. Windows 10 pre-installed.
3 days trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 but in vain.
First installed along with windows but not dual boot (grub) option only going straight to Windows.
Tried all methods on Ubuntu community to repair boot loader etc... Still in vain.
Then deleted windows and partitions from Ubuntu setup.
Created new partitions from Ubuntu setup.
1 efi file system 200mb.
2 ex4 rest of the space.
After installing same problem. Saying Boot device not found. Please install an OS on your hard disk. Hard 3F0.
Can some guide me and mention the complete process in reply how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you know how to boot to the BIOS or EUFI? Do that and check that secure boot and/or fast boot are disabled. I would then make a USB with gparted using another PC https://gparted.org/liveusb.php and then boot that usb and make your partitions again as you indicated, they look fine. Make sure to set the flags are set as boot & esp. Then put your 20.04 iso usb in and reboot. The installer should perform much better.

Comment: Thanks for giving me idea and and reminding me. So long before I faced the same problem but I forgot. Thanks for reminding me. Yes by deleting all Partitions from any other software instead of Ubuntu installation setup, resolved my problem. I used to partitions my ssd didn't used any external software. I used my live Ubuntu CD to be in Ubuntu try mode there is a utility already there named "disks" I used it to partition my ssd and all resolved. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem and solve it. This is because the boot partition is protected in HP computer and the boot information can not write in it. Using the third-party partition tools, you can see boot partipation though you delete all the partition using ubuntu-partition tools. You need delete all the partitions especially the boot partition using a third-party tool and then install ubuntu normally.

Comment: Can you suggest any third party tool for Ubuntu as right now I can run Ubuntu live preview via usb

Comment: I use a usb-boot windows7 with a tool named "DiskGenius". I don' know the similar software in ubuntu.